# Ruta de Archivos para que el JAR los ejecute

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jar

Tengo los siguientes métodos para llamar reportes y el icono de mi aplicación.

```
public void reporteArticulos () throws IOException,JRException{
    //File file = new File("");
    JasperReport archivo = JasperCompileManager.compileReport("Articulos.jrxml");
    Map parametros = new HashMap();
        parametros.put("mes", UltimosArticulos.mesArticulos.getSelectedItem());
        parametros.put("año", Integer.parseInt((String) UltimosArticulos.añoArticulos.getSelectedItem()));
        parametros.put("logo", "src/Images/logo_roble.png");
    Conectar con = new Conectar("jdbc:mysql://localhost/papeleria");
   JRDataSource data = new JREmptyDataSource();
    JasperPrint prin = JasperFillManager.fillReport(archivo, parametros,con.getConnection());
   JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(prin,"reporteArticulos.pdf");
    JasperViewer ver = new JasperViewer (prin,false);
    ver.setVisible(true);
    ver.setTitle("Reporte de Artículos");
}

setIconImage(new ImageIcon (getClass().getResource("../Images/iconoLogo.png")).getImage());
```

El jar no se me ejecuta si utilizo estos metodos he investigado y me dicen que es por la ruta de los archivos,he intentado ponerlos en varias direcciones y no me funciona. Si alguien sabe donde los debo guardar, Gracias.

Comment: Que error te da cuando lo ejecutas pude poner el error

Comment: El se ejecuta normalmente en Netbeans, pero el archivo jar no se ejecuta. En cambio cuando comento las lineas de codigo anteriormente mencionadas, alli si se ejecuta.